# IIS stopped serving static content over a certain (small) size

Tags: iis, static-content, iis-10

I'm really hoping somebody can help apply some sanity to this IIS issue that has been driving me crazy. I seem to be experiencing the same problem as the poor soul in this thread: https://forums.iis.net/t/1240175.aspx - IIS will not serve static content over a certain (arbitrary?) size. **NOTE: Previously had no problems serving static content on this same system**.

**OS:**
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 2004 19041.508

**Problem:**
Basically, IIS will not serve static content over a certain arbitrary size - static files over that size will just timeout eventually. Non-static content, for example asp files do not have this limit and load as expected regardless of size. This started happening seemingly out of nowhere with no directly related IIS/system/network/permission changes.

**Things I've Tried:**

- Yes, static content is turned on!
- Static compression enabled/disabled
- Same thing, every browser
- Completely virus/malware free
- Hardware and network healthy
- Don't see anything relevant in event logs
- Disabled ad blocker/anti-virus/firewall/etc.
- No proxies (except when Fiddler is running)
- Completely removed IIS (disabled feature, moved \inetpub and \windows\system32\inetsrv) and re-enabled feature which recreated them)
- Checked logs, enabled tracing
- SFC scan clean
- Checked permissions, toggled app user between IUSR and domain user

**Details:**

About a 1 or 1.5 months ago my local IIS stopped working, out of the blue. By out of the blue I mean the the previous day it was working fine as always and the next it stopped - without having done any system changes whatsoever. By stopped working I mean (eventually realized) that it was only static files that were not serving correctly. Unfortunately/fortunately, I noticed the problem because I had created the obligatory personal COVID tracker. It was html/js running against a .NET API back end. The pages stopped loading and I spent time wondering what I had borked in the code (which I also hadn't touched).
Eventually I realized no static content - images, css, js, html, txt etc. - was loading properly. I ran some tests and I found that there was a cutoff point in size of content that would load, but it is somewhat arbitrary. For example, the iisstart.png image in the default IIS website does not load - it's 97K. I replaced it with an 8k file that loads fine. I could get about 1500 bytes served in an html file - 1501 bytes would send it off the rails but 1500 worked. Same sort of thing was found for text files although I was able to send more than 1500 bytes - don't remember how much but did find a point where a 1 byte difference caused a problem.

**Test Load of Default IIS Website:**

IIS log is not helpful - it reports the failed attempt as a 200 but says it took 19 seconds. It **is** returning a **win32 status code of 121** though:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-10-23 13:36:12 127.0.0.1 GET /iisstart.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:82.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/82.0 http://localhost/ 200 0 121 18944
```

The failed tracing doesn't fire every time - not sure why. I've included an example output below.

Fiddler gives me this for the image request:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

For this site the actual html loads fine - it's only 696 bytes - the image it references does not though (97K).

If anybody can shed some light on this **or give me a direction in troubleshooting (I'm out of ideas short of Windows re-install and I don't want to do that)** I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

I'll put a snippet from my most recent FailedRequestLogFile output here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:80/iisstart.png"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
               processId="9916"
               verb="GET"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="TIME_TAKEN"
               statusCode="200"
               triggerStatusCode="0"
               timeTaken="10047"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">UPDATE_REQUEST_CACHE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>17</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="CachePolicy">0</Data>
  <Data Name="TimeToLive">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>OUTPUT_CACHE_UPDATE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="CachePolicy">NO_CACHE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{AC1D69F1-BF33-4CA0-9313-BCA13873E1DC}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>18</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Result">2</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>OUTPUT_CACHE_UPDATE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Result">NOT_FREQUENTLY_HIT</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{AC1D69F1-BF33-4CA0-9313-BCA13873E1DC}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">HttpCacheModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">512</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">UPDATE_REQUEST_CACHE</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">CustomLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1024</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">LOG_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">CustomLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1024</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">LOG_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">HttpLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">HttpLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ProtocolSupportModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ProtocolSupportModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">HttpCacheModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">HttpCacheModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">536870912</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">SEND_RESPONSE</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>14</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpsysCacheable">false</Data>
  <Data Name="Reason">23</Data>
  <Data Name="CachePolicy">0</Data>
  <Data Name="TimeToLive">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>HTTPSYS_CACHEABLE</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Reason">NO_CACHE_INVALIDATOR</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="CachePolicy">NO_CACHE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{AC1D69F1-BF33-4CA0-9313-BCA13873E1DC}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>35</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>47</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Headers">Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 19:11:06 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: &quot;37b28017a7a8d61:0&quot;
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>48</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-29T21:16:48.320Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="9916" ThreadID="23540"/>
  <Computer>NEBULA</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000002-0005-F300-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="FileName">\\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.png</Data>
  <Data Name="Offset">0</Data>
  <Data Name="Size">98757</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_FILE</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
</failedRequest>
```